# How to toggle a set of buttons with in a userscript when clicking one button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, userscripts

This may be poorly worded, so I'll try to explain better.

Im trying to create a userscript that will, when a button is clicked, display a set of other buttons to click to do various things below that button. Then, upon clicking the button again, the set of other buttons would disappear. Like a toggleable dropdown.

Currently, this is what the userscript looks like:

```js
// ==/UserScript==

var menuButton       = document.createElement ('div');
menuButton.innerHTML = '<button id="mainButton" type="button">'
                + 'Glass</button>'
                ;
menuButton.setAttribute ('id', 'myContainer');
document.body.appendChild (menuButton);

//Click listener
document.getElementById ("mainButton").addEventListener (
    "click", openStuff, false
);

function openStuff (zEvent) {
    /*--- Dummy action, just adds a line of text to the top
        of the screen.
    */
    var menuButton       = document.createElement ('p');
    menuButton.innerHTML = 'Clicked.';
    document.getElementById ("myContainer").appendChild (menuButton);
}
// Style
GM_addStyle ( `
    #myContainer {
        position:               absolute;
        top:                    0;
        left:                   0;
        font-size:              20px;
        z-index:                1100;
    }
    #mainButton {
        cursor:                 pointer;
    }
    #myContainer p {
        color:                  black;
    }
` );
```

Currently, it just adds a transparent line of dummy text below the button whenever its clicked. I have no experience with CSS (copy/pasted the styling from a guide), and my experience of JS comes from Node.js, so I'm very, very lost here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would having a single-element accordion do the trick? https://dev.to/link2twenty/native-html-accordion-2fma Accordions are available in HTML natively without having to use any JS.

Answer (score 1):

Updated post:

1. you can now copy and paste the solution.  We've added both the css and js directly to the html file.  notice that the style tags go into the head section and the script tag goes at the bottom just before the closing body tag
2. let's examine more closely the css and js.
   a) we set the height of the container to the view height. strictly speaking we don't have to do this but I wanted to show alignment
   b) we set the display to flex.  Google flexbox to learn more but in short this solves a lot of problems and makes it really easy to position elements
   c) we set the flex direction to column which means the direct children in the container will flow down the column as opposed to across a row
   d) justify-content:center aligns to center along the major axis. align-items:center aligns to center along the minor axis.  The axisis are column and row.  flex-direction defines the major axis.
   e) we start out with #buttons display set to none to hide it
   f) #buttons.showme means for the element #button when it has class .showme

The js is pretty starightforward.  the only item of note is  buttons.classList.toggle("showme"); which just toggles (adds and removes) the class when clicked.

Let me know if this makes sense or we can maybe do a zoom call to go over in more detail

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>help</title>
   <style>
      #container {
         height: 100vh;
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: column;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center;
         border: solid 1px black;
         flex-direction: column;
      }

      #buttons {
         display: none;
      }

      #buttons.showme {
         display: block;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='container'>
  <div>
    <button onclick='toggleMe()'>click me</button>
  </div>
  <div id='buttons'>

    <button onclick='dostuff(0)'>button 1</button>
    <button onclick='dostuff(1)'>button 2</button>

  </div>

</div>

<script>
function toggleMe() {

  var buttons = document.getElementById('buttons')
  buttons.classList.toggle("showme");
}

function dostuff(idx) {

  if (idx == 0) alert("button 1 action")
  else alert("button 2 action")
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is very nice, and I can see that this code works. While I don't understand the CSS at all (itll always be a mystery to me in some way lol), I do understand the HTML and the JS. What i dont understand though is where the HTML and JS go. Do I completely undo what I have to display the button and give it a func currently? Do I just add it below that? And where does the HTML go at all?